# Api to delete all subjects at one go in confluent schema registry

Tags: confluent-schema-registry

Does confluent schema registry facilitates an API to delete all subjects at one go. I'm aware confluent provides deletion with respect to specific subjects.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: http://ipAddress/schema-registry/subjects/{subject_id}
Here subject_id - Id of the subject to be deleted 
postMethod: DELETE
Expectation: Without giving subject_id ; Need to delete all subjects registered in schema registry

Comment: @SureshGanesan Nah, doesn't work that way, tried just now.

Comment: @LexSav - Do you have any suggestion or alternative?

Comment: @SureshGanesan I don't. Left the comment so no one else would spend time trying that approach.